# Postgres Index-only-scan: can we ignore the visibility map or avoid heap fetches?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Sorry, lots of context before the actual question as we've thoroughly researched this and I wanted to give you full context.

**Some context**: Postgres index-only-scans rely on the visibility map (VM). If a page is not marked as fully-visible in the visibility map, Postgres fetches that page to ensure the data is visible to this transaction, even when doing index only scans. Unfortunately, this can greatly slowdown index only scans. The index might return results from 10k rows, but the index itself only spans 50 pages (very fast in terms of IO). However, if VM isn't set, it makes and extra 10k heap fetches (200x slower in terms of IO).

**Details**: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#The_Visibility_Map_.28and_other_relation_forks.29

**Try it yourself**: EXPLAIN ANALYZE an index only query, before and after a VACUUM. You can see the number of heap fetches go down after the VACUUM (assuming you had some dirty pages in the VM before)

**Already tried**: We're already tuned autovacuum, and we're vacuuming regularly. This helps a lot, but we'd like to get even faster.

**Question (finally)**: Is it possible to skip heap fetches when doing index only scans? I'm aware we wouldn't have perfect MVCC when reading, but we're okay with that. The data in the index is close enough, and it's definitely not worth the overhead of thousands of heap fetches to make sure we're not looking at slightly stale data. To borrow a term from NoSQL, we'd be fine with "eventual consistency" reads.

Comment: No, not possible unless you hack the Postgres source code.

Comment: This feature would be even more useful for COUNT that could rely only on index scans (and you don't care about the exact value). Instead PG always checks the Heap for visibility, making the COUNT much slower...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want in PostgreSQL as it stands. It'd be interesting to do but a fair bit of work, very unlikely to be accepted into core, extremely hard to do with an extension, and likely to have worse side-effects than you probably expect.

You'd basically have to add a `DIRTY READ` isolation level to PostgreSQL, except that it'd be even weaker than that because it might also **return deleted data**, the **old versions of updated rows**, and **multiple values from unique indexes**. This latter issue would potentially upset the query planner quite a bit, since it's allowed to assume that results from unique indexes will be unique.

I see the chances of such a change being accepted into PostgreSQL core as very close to zero. The possible use cases are very limited.

The only way I could see of justifying adding such a feature would be to make recovery from clog loss/corruption and accidental deletion easier by supporting raw reads. That'd make most sense for seqscans of the heap rather than index-only scans.

It would probably make more sense to solve this another way, such as a non-durable caching layer (Redis etc) on top of the DB for data you don't need perfectly fresh.

Comment: I feared as much, and all my reading led me to believe that, but I figured I'd double check.

I love PGs durability and MVCC implementation, but performance has been a pain point.

thanks.

Comment: Instead of changing everything... why not allow dirty reads from indexes only for specific queries? e.g. `WITH DIRTY READ SELECT COUNT...`

Comment: @collimarco Because inside PostgreSQL everything in a query uses the same snapshot. Including system catalog access. It'd probably be possible, but it's far from as simple as you might expect. And what if the index definition has changed? etc.